# converting a column of object values to float or integers. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,026,765'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, typeerror, valueerror

```
  dfproduction = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chessybo/Oil-Spill-map/master/Oil%20Spill%20Data%20-%20Crude%20Oil%2C%20Gas%20Well%20Liquids%20or%20Associated%20Products%20(H-8)/production%20data/Crude%20Oil%20Production%20and%20Well%20Counts%20(since%201935).csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

I want to convert this data to numbers (namely the column, 'Crude Oil Production (Mbbl)') such as float or int.

currently the dtype is object

```
    print(dfproduction.dtypes)
MasterYear                                  int64
Crude Oil Production (Mbbl)                object
Daily Avg. Production (Mbbl/day)           object
Number of Producing Wells                  object
Percent Change in Production               object
Avg. Per Well Production (bbl/day)        float64
Crude Oil Reserves as of Jan. 1 (Mbbl)     object
info                                       object
dtype: object
```

however any attempt to do so results in some form of error.

```
dfproduction['Crude Oil Production (Mbbl)'].astype('int')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,026,765'

dfproduction['Crude Oil Production (Mbbl)'].astype('float')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '375,617'
```

UPDATE:

The issue was the commas in the numbers, I removed the commas and reuploaded the data. only now i recieve the following error..

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 83: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Well the error is clear: it contains comma separators for the thousands, but Python's `int(..)` function can not handle that. So you need to remove these.

Comment: I just downloaded the data and couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: RafaelC i updated the data to remove the commas, but now I get UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 83: invalid start byte

Comment: ClayChester: then please edit the question with updated example. This is two questions-in-one: comma-as-thousands-separator and the Unicode decode. Both are duplicates of existing questions.

Comment: I will include an update, but these are not copies of existing questions. searching for the error does not bring up the commas-as-separators. as the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to remove the commas.

```
dfproduction['Crude Oil Production (Mbbl)'].str.replace(r',', '').astype('int')
```